# Windows 7 drive (P:|)shared with Everyone but not accessible by Windows XP computers on our network

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

I'm trying to share my P:\ drive on a Windows 7 (Pro) PC with other PCs (WinXP) on my network. 
I shared it and set permissions to give Everyone Full Control.

**Symptoms**

- Computer XP(different computer on the network) ***can* access**  **\win7\users\ public**  (and copy files to it and edit files in that folder)  but not the \win7\p:\
- **Folders** I've shared on the Windows 7 PC are **visible** to the XP computers but just not accessible . From the other WinXP PCs on the LAN accessing the Win7 PC, I get "win7\p not accessible. You might not have permission to use the network resource. "  "Access Denied".

**Edit:**  I've to Advanced Sharing options set to have the following enabled:

- Network Discovery
- File and Printer sharing
- Sharing so anyone can read/write files to public folders.
- **128 bit encryption**  (perhaps this is an issue? Perhaps it should be set to 40 bit encryption?)
- Allow Windows to manage homegroup.
- XP machines are set to not use Simple File Sharing.

**Other Things I've Tried**

- Confirmed **all computers** are in the **MSHOME** workgroup.
- **Turned off** the Windows 7 **Firewall**, briefly. Problem persisted.
- Tried the Windows 7 Network Troubleshooter. Just led me around in a circle saying "found problem...need more information". The links from there led back to the Network Troubleshooter.
- tried **disabling** the **Firewall** on the Windows **XP** machine. No joy.
- Verified the XP machines are both on **Win XP SP3** and both have "download updates" turned on.
- Installed IE8 on the XP machine1. (Previously it had IE 6). Still no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Curious: Are you sharing the ROOT of P:? Or a subfolder?

Comment: And also: What is the SECONDARY error within the dialogue. For instance, it may be "Access is Denied" or "Unknown username or bad password."

Comment: @tcv :  I'm sharing the root of P:  and the secondary error is "Access Denied"

Comment: Ok, I can duplicate that with my 7 workstation. Curious: What happens if you share a subfolder. I've seen this problem before in Vista and I'll have to flog myself to remember what I did...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this on the Windows 7 machine:

1. Open Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy.
2. Click on Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment on the left.
3. Double-click "Deny access to this computer from network".
4. Select Guest and click Remove.
5. click OK.
6. **EDIT:** Ensure in the Permissions for the network share, that Guest is included, since it's no longer part of the Everyone group.
7. Use regedit to go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` and create or modify the value of LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy (32-bit dword) to 1, so the remote logon token will not be filtered (see [here](http://www.grantburton.com/?tag=localaccounttokenfilterpolicy)).

Comment: There were no Users listed in that field (i.e., Guest had never been added)

Comment: @Clay Nichols: See my edit.

Comment: I'll try that.
BTW, That fix says it's for allowing another computer to access Vista if they are on different domains. We don't use domains we use Workgroups and they're all on the same workgroup.

Comment: @Clay Nichols: Doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: @Clay Nichols: Thanks for the points. For the benefit of future : Which one worked?

Comment: @harrymc:  Resolved after I did #4,5,6 on the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: This can be fixed for some people by just doing #6 and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Network and Sharing Center` then click on `Advanced sharing settings`.

Make sure that `File and printer sharing` is set to on and `Password protected sharing` is turned off.

Then when you access the machine from the network, it should work - if you still have problems, write in comments and I will try to help further.

Comment: I've got that set already (I should have included that in the question).

Comment: And, of course, still having the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to press alt in any folder and go to tools > Folder Options. Under view uncheck "use simple file sharing". Then, on the folder, as well as having everyone selected for full control or whatever, make sure in the seporate security tab you have done the same. Network logons try to use guest and this does not have control by default.

Comment: Wil - I assume 'turn off Simple.." is for the XP PCs? They are already set to NOT use Simple Sharing.

Comment: This is for the 7 machine as it does some various registry and policy changes re: guest account and network permissions.

Comment: Hmmm... on the Win7 machine in the View tab I don't see "Simple Sharing" I think that's been renamed in Win7 to "Use Sharing Wizard", right?

Comment: I turned off "Use Sharing Wizard" on the Win7 PC and restarted it. Problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there was an update for Windows XP a few months ago, which is needed to be able to connect with new versions of windows. check in windows update center, if you have all updates + service pack 3 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a user(administrator) with same name and password on the xp and windows 7 machine.

Comment: I suspect this might work as well if we're using Simple Sharing, but I've not tested it.

Comment: That did it for me. Entered the actual Windows user name and password instead of just guest. Connecting Mac (*Finder* → *Go* → *Connect to Server*) to Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the steps mentioned, but finally fixed my own issue:

- Right-click the drive and select *Properties* (drive or any folder you want to share)
- Select the *Security* tab
- Click `[Edit]`
- Add `Everyone` to give full control to all users
- Apply

It works great for me now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workable but ugly workaround:

- Change the user account type to administrator and set a basic password, "pass" for example.
- When my XP machine asks for username and password I type [computername]/[admin user name] and the password you set.

This allows you to log into the machine although it may not be great for all occasions (and have security side effects)

Comment: It works also with less priveedged guest accounts.