# XP,Turned on simple file sharing and other computers can't open my files?

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing

I was having problems, so I turned simple file sharing back on a week or so ago.

Other computers can see my files but can't open them.

I don't have the tabs to alter the permissions now.

I think I just need to refresh the permissions.

What do I need to do ?

EDIT:
Turned simple sharing off and heres my settings.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Simple File Sharing is on, all network users authenticate as the Guest account.
If off, then network users authenticate as themselves.

So you either need to add permissions on the share for the Guest account (normally enabled automatically when Simple File Sharing is set on), or disable Simple File Sharing and give all user accounts permissions on the share.

Comment: My answer was a bit messed-up, so I simplified it.

Comment: Yes, if account names are different per each computer (much simpler if all users are called "Administrator"). Only PCs with shares are concerned.

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: That's why Microsoft invented Simple File Sharing, where you only have to worry about Guest.

Comment: See this other [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/100645/windows-7-drive-pshared-with-everyone-but-not-accessible-by-windows-xp-comput/102050#102050) of mine.

Comment: Did you look in share's Properties / Sharing tab / Advanced Sharing / Permissions, if Guest is there. For XP, Everyone includes Guest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the tabs for permissions because simple file sharing hides them from you. You need to disable simple file sharing in order to get the tabs back.

See [the Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307874) or more info.

---

Looking at the ACL in your picture, if you want other machines to be able to view your files, add the "Everyone" group to the list and give them read permissions. That should suffice.

Comment: They will always be there, simple file sharing just makes them a little transparent to the end user. Enabling it will give you a better idea of why others cant access the content. Can you post a screenshot of the advanced sharing settings?